# c# MVC ViewModel is not passing to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

And a ViewModel to contain one instance and a list of the above:

```
public class PeopleSearchViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }
    public List<PersonViewModel> People { get; set; }
}
```

Then my View:

```
@model PeopleSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Whatever"/>
}
```

And finally the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(PeopleSearchViewModel theModelIsntPassing)
{
}
```

The model is not being passed to the controller on form submission?
Or maybe it is, but the individual properties aren't populated.

The ActionResult `Search` method is definitely being called, just `theModelIsntPassing` has no values in its nested property

Comment: Is `PatientSearchPageViewModel` the correct model to be receiving? Can we see it's definition?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It's supposed to be the same `PeopleSearchViewModel` as defined in the class and view.

Comment: Your ActionResult function must match the first argument in `Html.BeginForm`. See an example here: [MVC HtmlBeginForm](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx)

Comment: No sorry that was also a typo from a previous version, corrected now. The correct Action is being called on my controller but the model doesn't pass.

Comment: Can we please see the full code of the controller, right now, it isn't doing anything... If not, put a breakpoint and analyze what `theModelIsntPassing` is containing...

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't meaning to do `m.People.Firstname` instead of `m.Person.Firstname`?

Comment: I've put a breakpoint on the next line of that controller method and the `theModelIsntPassing` instance contains an instance of each of the properties. The list has count = 0 and the `PersonViewModel` contains nulls and a 0 id. There is nothing else surrounding the controller other than the namespace because I am simply testing how to pass this viewModel to a controller.

Comment: With only the code posted, `People` will always be empty.

Comment: `People` is for returning search results, which will be written in the controller when I can figure out how to pass someone's first name to the controller via the ViewModel

Comment: Inspect the `Request` object, should contain some form values. Might give you a clue.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with your structure. Why have `person` and then `people`? Why not just `people`? Please update your controller to include what you're doing with it.

Comment: In the Request.Forms object, the parameter is there as a key/val pair. `Person.FirstName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are having both HiddenFor and TextBoxFor for FirstName. 
Please try comment/remove `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)` statement in your view

```
@model PeopleSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)*@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Person.Firstname)

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Whatever"/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. In the tutorial I was looking at it, it said this was a necessary entry for it to work. But maybe there wasn't a textBoxFor in there... I'll have another look.